# How to multiply values coming from backend with numbers?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a script that takes the parameter names and then embeds their values in the table, which is shown in the screenshot. Actually, I need to multiply this number that equals 0.00000407 by another number. How do I do that?[image]`

I haven't yet had a chance to do math with these types of data, but I need to finish it soon.

HTML below:

```
<div class="volume-label">Profability 100mh/24ч</div>
        <div id="hashrentReward">
<span style="color:#000000;"><strong></strong></span>
        </div>
```

JS Code

```
    function refreshData(){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    { 
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
        {
        console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
            makeValuesMain(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
        else if(xmlHttp.status != 200 && xmlHttp.status != 0)
        {
            console.log('HTTP return code is ' + xmlHttp.status);
            makeValuesMain('');
        }
    }   
    
    url = location.protocol + '//' + '' + '/api/pool';
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null); }

function makeValuesMain(json_string) {
    try {
        var obj = JSON.parse(json_string);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        if(e instanceof SyntaxError) console.log(e);
        var obj = {result:{}}, n_a = '-';
        obj.result['unpaidBalance'] = n_a;
        obj.result['unconfirmedBalance'] = n_a;
        obj.result['workersOnline'] = n_a;
        obj.result['currentHashrate'] = n_a;
        obj.result['dayReward'] = n_a;
        obj.result['lastShare'] = n_a;
        obj.result['totalPaid'] = n_a;
        obj.result['blocksFound'] = n_a;
    }

    console.log(obj.result);
    drawValues(obj.result); 
}


function drawValues(values)
{
    var graphHeader = '';

    for(var key in values)
    {
        if(key == 'avgHashrate')
        {
            graphHeader = values[key];
            continue;
        }

        if(key == 'speed')
        {
            graph_data = values[key];
            continue;
        }
        var el_id = key.charAt(0) + key.slice(1),
            el = document.getElementById(el_id);

        if(typeof(el) != 'undefined' && el != null)
        {
            spans = el.getElementsByTagName('span'), 
            spans[0].innerHTML = '<b>' + values[key] + '</b>';
        }
    }}
```

Comment: In js: `value * otherValue`. You should show us the js code that populates the html, to give better answers.

Comment: You need to identify the key for the value you want to change (you can do that with `console.log(values);` in `drawValues` function. Then do the calculation for that specific value and output to the `span`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify what type of backend do you have? I guess you made an API, right? Then you should make an http request to the backend with javascript and then parse the response :D

But if you want just multiply the values, you just have to do

```js
item1 * item2
```

Comment: Added JS code, please view it